# Dynamically loading columns data into table in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I want to get table head data dynamically how i do that??

My HTML:-

```html
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr *ngFor="let SR of StockReport;">
                        <td>
                            <b></b>
                        </td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                        <td><b></b></td>
                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let SR of StockReport;let inx=index">
                        <td style="width: 11%;">{{inx+1}} </td>
                        <td>{{SR.ItemName}} </td>
                        <td align="right">{{SR.Inward}} </td>
                        <td align="right"> {{SR.Outward}}</td>
                        <td align="right">{{SR.Stock}} </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

In the above code, the columns are getting created successfully but the table head data is not working

json data:-
{
"ItemName": "CV CPU",
"Inward": "50.00",
"Outward": "0.00",
"Stock": "50.00"
},

Comment: can you create stackblitz ?

Comment: try my code given in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo-zcesna

```
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Sr. No.</td>
                        <td *ngFor="let key of tableHeader ">
                            <b>{{key}}</b>
                        </td>
                         
                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let SR of StockReport; let i = index">
                        <td style="width: 11%;">{{i+1}} </td>
                        <td>{{SR.BranchID}} </td>
                         <td align="right">{{SR.Brand}} </td>
                       
                        <td align="right">{{SR.Inward}} </td>
                        
                        <td align="right">{{SR.ItemID}} </td>
                         <td>{{SR.ItemName}} </td>
                         <td>{{SR.ItemSubGrp}} </td>
                         <td align="right">{{SR.ModelNO}} </td> 
                         
                          <td align="right"> {{SR.Outward}}</td>
                          <td align="right">{{SR.Stock}} </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: thats not working there appear key index only not key names

Comment: it's works bt i want it directly through api response

Comment: whatever API response you are getting JSON map it to variable then use in template. This is approach you have to use. I given sample JSON in component. If you feel this works dont forget to accept and upvote answer. Thanks

Comment: @sHaRjAs you got my points ? you have to handle in API call.

Comment: How i randomly select these keys and keyvalues

Comment: Randomly means can you add in details in question because answer was to question which you ask.

Comment: i want load table through api response.there i get a json map and so the table head data and table row data are listed.bt i want to list table head data and table row data which i want thats my question

Comment: can you add your code stackblitz with api sample. if you already using `StockReport` this from API response then you my code same as it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216714/discussion-between-sharjas-and-aviboy2006).

Comment: Accept this answer if this help you. @sHaRjAs